# How do I control this power circuit using an MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, ac, power-electronics, heat, triac

I'd like to use [this heater element](http://www.ferrotechniek.com/thick_film_heaters/products/fth_mk2.aspx) for a project I'm working on. It looks like a good product but there is unfortunately not much documentation available, but I think it's basically a simple resistive load that can operate from 230V AC. So I started to look around to see how I could control the temperature of this heater and found an interesting circuit in [*Power Semiconductor Applications*](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/APPCHP6.pdf) (chapter 6.2.2) by Philips:

[image]

This circuit produces the following output:

[image]

This looks like it could do the job for me. According to the description, it is controlled by the resistance of the potentiometer *R2*.

Now my question is, instead of a manual potentiometer, how can I modify this circuit to control it electrically, with an MCU (microcontroller)?

Alternatively, what other circuit could I use that can be controlled using an MCU that would achieve the same ends?

Note, I'd also prefer to keep this galvanically isolated from the MCU. I believe this could be achieved using an optocoupler, but I'm not a power expert, so I'm not sure which kind I need here.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: That kind of circuit is remarkably ill-suited to being controlled by a microcontroller.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I know, that's why I'm asking how to modify it. I'm open to suggestions about alternatives, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider an SSR controlled with the MCU via PWM and with a short (~2 second) proportional cycle. You can use a temperature sensor and feedback control or open loop, depending on requirements.

The SSR provides the isolation, You'll need a large-ish heat sink and/or fan for any solid-state switching.

You should also consider what happens when (not if) the SSR or micro gets stuck on and make sure there is adequate safety provisions (maybe a thermal cutoff or other protections) to prevent injury or property damage.

What you've shown is a phase control- it will cause a lot of electrical noise and is probably unnecessary for this application.

Comment: Good point about phase control. Would triggering only at zero-crossings be less noisy? Does the SSR do that automatically? Are there any other advantages of the SSR over a thyristor?

Comment: The problem with an SSR is that it's wildly expensive (and big) compared to anything that you can build with a triac.

Comment: By the way, I added a picture of what the output is, this doesn't look like phase control for me.

Comment: @Pigrew Yes, the zero crossing type would be less noisy- but there might be more beat problems as the cycle is shortened. An AC SSR is just a thyristor with an optocoupler, snubber, and drive circuit for the LED. The OP can build one himself.

Comment: @Venemo Are you planning on using it with a vacuum cleaner motor load? Your link is to an almost purely resistive heater.

Comment: I plan to use this with the exact product I linked. Perhaps it wouldn't work with a resistive load?

Comment: It will work- it's basically a manual dimmer circuit (phase control).

Comment: I'd also be okay with building an SSR myself if it allows me to control the thing with an MCU. Like I said, I'm open to suggestions. I've seen a circuit which had two MOSFETs instead of a triac, maybe that combined with an optotransistor would be better suited for this?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. MOSFETs are not better for switching 230VAC. Check out the MOC3063 zero-crossing triac driver.

Comment: Right now I have a triac-out optocoupler (which has zero-cross detection) combined with a BTA140 triac. This is simple and it works, but it does not allow to control the temperature of the heater, just to turn it on or off.

Comment: You want to turn it on more of the 2 seconds when it's too cold and less of the 2 seconds when it's too hot.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That sounds a little bit too simple, doesn't it?